# Is there any alternate way to find my organizations code coverage?

Tags: code-coverage, gack

When I clicked "Estimate your organization's code coverage" in Apex Classes from Setup Menu,

[image]

I got the following error.

[image]

Why this error coming? Is there any other alternate approach to find my organization's overall code coverage? Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

Try compiling all your code. I believe you'll get a compilation error. Correct any errors, clear your code coverage, then run all tests. After this, you should be able to calculate your code coverage.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. I did and it is displaying as "Compilation Complete" and Compilation Successful. Then I tried "Estimate your organization's coder coverage" still getting same issue. Where should i see compilation errors?

Comment: Use the "clear code coverage" button, then click "run all tests". This should clear the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should go to developer console and choose Test->Run all, once the tests run you will have coverage displayed.